# Create array of dates based on inputs

Tags: php, date

Given these two YYYYMM strings:

```
$start = "201301";
$end = "201303";
```

I would like to derive an array like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '20130101',
    1 => '20130131',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '20130201',
    1 => '20130228',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '20130301',
    1 => '20130331',
  ),
)
```

I've tried a few things with date() and mktime() but nothing decent so far.

What's a nice way to do this?

Comment: inner arrays must have first and last day of those months ? or all days ?

Comment: @Svetlio, inner arrays have two values, first day of month and last day of month.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but setting up an array with first and last day of each month looks strange to me. Maybe the PHP DateTime classes are something for you; especially [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/class.dateperiod.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/class.dateinterval.php).

Answer (score 2):

With [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$start = "201301";
$end = "201303";

$dateNiceStart = substr($start,0,4).'-'.substr($start,4).'-01';
$dateNiceEnd = substr($end,0,4).'-'.substr($end,4).'-';

// Days count in month
$endDays = date('t',strtotime($dateNiceEnd.'01'));
$dateNiceEnd .= $endDays;

$startObj = new DateTime($dateNiceStart);
$endObj = new DateTime($dateNiceEnd);

$temp = clone $startObj;

$arr = array();
// Adding first month
//Using first day and last day
$temp->modify( 'first day of this month' );
$start = $temp->format('Ymd');
$temp->modify( 'last day of this month' );
$end = $temp->format('Ymd');

$arr[] = array($start, $end);
do{
    // for next month
    $temp->modify( 'first day of next month' );
    $start = $temp->format('Ymd');
    $temp->modify( 'last day of this month' );
    $end = $temp->format('Ymd');

    $arr[] = array($start, $end);

    // This line edited to work properly in different years, thanks to @Adidi
    $interval = $endObj->diff($temp)->format('%y%m%d');
}
while ($interval!=0);

print_R($arr);
```

Main key is ***first/last*** day of **next/this** month usage.

Comment: -1 This solution is not good if it's different year - try to set `$end = "201403";`

Comment: you have syntax error - there: `$interval = $endObj->diff($temp)->format('%y%m%d');`

Comment: what IDE are you using :) ?

Comment: Eclipse with PDT. Sometimes it help a lot, but sometimes make me crazy.

Comment: Eclipse is horrible for PHP - yee

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Which you need is format string "t":

> **t** Number of days in the given month    28 through 31

Answer (score 1):

Here is easy way to loop it..

```
$start  = "201301";
$end    = "201303";

$start_time = strtotime(implode('-',str_split($start,4)));
$end_time = strtotime(implode('-',str_split($end,4)));

$array = array();
if($start_time <= $end_time){
    while($start_time <= $end_time){
        $month = date('F', $start_time);
        $array[] = array(
            date('Ymd', strtotime("first day of {$month}", $start_time)),
            date('Ymd', strtotime("last day of {$month}", $start_time)));
        $start_time = strtotime("next month", $start_time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
    $first = '2013'.($i<10 ? '0'.$i : $i).'01';
    $last = date('Ymt', strtotime($first));
    $myArray[] = array($first, $last);
}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the months like so:

```
function date_range($start, $end)
{
    $start = strtotime("$start01");
    $end = strtotime("$end01");

    $res = array();

    while ($start < $end) {
        $next = strtotime("+1 month -1 day", $start);
        $res[] = array(
            date('Ymd', $start),
            date('Ymd', $next),
        );
        $start = $next;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
$start = "201301";
$end = "201309";

function getDateTimeByString($str_date){
    preg_match('/^([\d]{4})([\d]{2})$/',$str_date,$matches);
    $dt = null;
    if($matches){
        $dt = new DateTime();
        $dt->setDate($matches[1],$matches[2],1);   
    }
    return $dt;      
}


$start_dt = getDateTimeByString($start);
$end_dt = getDateTimeByString($end);

$output = array();

while($start_dt->getTimestamp() <= $end_dt->getTimestamp()){
    $arr = array(); 
    $arr[] = $start_dt->format('Ymd');
    $start_dt->modify('last day of this month');
    $arr[] = $start_dt->format('Ymd');

    $output[] = $arr;  

    $start_dt->modify('first day of next month');
}


print_r($output);
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130101
            [1] => 20130131
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130201
            [1] => 20130228
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130301
            [1] => 20130331
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130401
            [1] => 20130430
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130501
            [1] => 20130531
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130601
            [1] => 20130630
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130701
            [1] => 20130731
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130801
            [1] => 20130831
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20130901
            [1] => 20130930
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with these functions :

```
function get_date_range ($start, $end) {

    $dates = array();

    $start = strtotime($start .'01');
    $end    = strtotime($end .'01');

    while ($start <= $end) {
        $dates [] = array(date('Ym01', $start), date('Ymt', $start));
        $start  = strtotime(add_month(date('Y-m-01', $start), 1));
    }

    return $dates;
}

function add_month($date_value, $months, $format = 'm/d/Y') {
    $date = new DateTime($date_value);
    $start_day = $date->format('j');

    $date->modify("+{$months} month");
    $end_day = $date->format('j');

    if ($start_day != $end_day)
        $date->modify('last day of last month');

    return $date->format($format);
}

$start = "201301";
$end    = "201303";

$dates = get_date_range($start, $end);

print_r($dates);
```

Here the `add_month` function will help you to avoid problems with the date when adding one month to January 31st.

If you use `strtotime` it will go to March when adding 1 month to January 31st..
Output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-01
            [1] => 2013-01-31
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-02-01
            [1] => 2013-02-28
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-03-01
            [1] => 2013-03-31
        )

)
```

Hope this helps you :)